# Extracting two substrings from one string

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to extract the `00` and `02` from the line below into Strings.

```
invokestatic:indexbyte1=00 indexbyte2=02
```

I am using this code, but it's not working correctly:

```
String parse = "invokestatic:indexbyte1=00 indexbyte2=02";

String first = parse.substring(check.indexOf("=") + 1);
String second= parse.substring(check.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
```

This seems to work for the seconds string, but the first strings value is

```
00 indexbyte2=02
```

I want to catch just the two digits and not the rest of the string.

Comment: Step 1: Split on whitespace. Step 2: Split on `=`.

Comment: @Dawson You'll need to tell `substring()` when to stop.

Comment: Is the format always the same? If so you could use a regex with `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Comment: Do you know the length of the part you want after the '=' or do you know it will get followed by a space ' '?

Comment: `=(.*?)\s` for your reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the second parameter in substring method it will result in a substring from the starting index to the end of string that's why you get "00 indexbyte2=02" for `first`.

Specify the last index only to extract two digits when you extract value for `first`

```
String first = parse.substring(check.indexOf("=") + 1, check.indexOf("=") + 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex pattern with groups, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "invokestatic:indexbyte1=00 indexbyte2=02";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*indexbyte1=(\\d*) indexbyte2=(\\d*)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String first = parse.substring(check.indexOf("=") + 1, check.indexOf("=") + 3);
```

`check.indexOf("=") + 3` will take the `02` and will be the [endindex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) for the substring. Presently you are not specifying the endindex hence it is taking the `indexbyte2=02` as well since substring does not know where to stop hence it parses down till the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
String parse = "invokestatic:indexbyte1=00 indexbyte2=02";

        String first = parse.substring(parse.indexOf("=") + 1,
                parse.indexOf("=") + 3);
        String second = parse.substring(parse.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
        System.out.println(first + ",   " + second);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Pattern`, `Matcher` clases.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<==)\\d+").matcher(string);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

substring also has an endIndex. See the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

If the input has the basic form `invokestatic:indexbyte1=00 indexbyte2=02 ... indexbyte99=99` you could use a regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("indexbyte\\d+=([a-fA-F0-9]{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while( m.find() ) {
  String idxByte = m.group(1);
  //handle the byte here
}
```

This assumes that the identifier for those bytes is `indexbyteN` but this can be replaced with another identifier. Further this assumes the bytes are provided in hex, i.e. 2 hex characters (case insensitive here).